# Issue in getting random messages from Array using UILocalNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I used the following line of code for getting local notification.

```
Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"UILocalNotification");
if (cls != nil) {

    UILocalNotification *notif = [[cls alloc] init];
    notif.fireDate = itemDate;
    notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    NSMutableArray *newArray=[[self appDelegate].defaultsvalue objectForKey:@"ArrayMessage"];

    //int index = arc4random() % [newArray count];
    notif.alertBody =[newArray objectAtIndex:arc4random() % [newArray count]];

    notif.alertAction = @"Show me";
    notif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    notif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

    notif.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;

    NSDictionary *userDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[newArray objectAtIndex:arc4random() % [newArray count]]
                                                         forKey:@"kRemindMeNotificationDataKey"];
    notif.userInfo = userDict;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
}
```

From the above code "newArray" is NSMutable Array, in it 100 message is stored. Now i want to notify randomly message from that array everyday at 8:00 AM.

From the above code i got same message everyday. I want random message from that array.

Thanks in adv..!

Comment: What is your problem? Update your question.

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  Please rewrite it.

Comment: Now please refer the question

Comment: this will not work you should create the diff local notification on each day. right now what happening that from the 100 message will take message and schedule that message for evert day.

Comment: So what can i do now?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,  You have to create multiple notification "Objects"

```
    NSInteger intervals = 0;
    for (int i =0; i<60; i++) {
        // creating notification interval
        // where 60 = seconds, so add your seconds here
        intervals = intervals + 60;
        NSDate *newDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:intervals];
        Class cls = NSClassFromString(NSStringFromClass([UILocalNotification class]));
        if (cls != nil) {
            UILocalNotification *notification = [[cls alloc] init];
            notification.fireDate = newDate;
            notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
            notification.alertAction = @"Clear";

            //if you want to repeat same notification with some time interavals 
            notification.repeatInterval = kCFCalendarUnitSecond;

            //notification with sound
            notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

            //notification with vibrate
            AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);

            if (array.count>0) {
                NSInteger ran = arc4random() % array.count;
                notification.alertBody = [self randomMessage:ran];
                NSDictionary *userDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"ANYIDENTIFIER" forKey:kRemindMeNotificationDataKey];
                notification.userInfo = userDict;
            }

            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
        }
    }
```